# MongoDB isn't connecting to the server 127.0.0.1:27017 and showing target machine actively refused it

Tags: windows, mongodb

I run this command `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe` start my mongoDB but it is showing this error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-04-17T18:28:32.535+0530 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-04-17T18:28:32.541+0530 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-04-17T18:28:32.541+0530 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

My mongoDB compass isn't connecting too..

Answer (score 0):

`mongo` (`mongo.exe` for windows users) does not start the server. It is used to connect to a server which is already running.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `mongod` in the command line  before connecting to the server, it will initialite it. You can't connect to the server you haven't started

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out this last line mp at \bin\mongodb.cfg. becomes #mp:
Restart mongod.

You can check whether your mongodb is running at the service (task Manager->Services ->Mongodb)..(Make sure you click *Property* to see all those setting)

Hope this helps.